# Upgrade datalab to new release

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Today when I open it, I saw that all my files have disappeared inside it and there is a word of version upgrade - new version is available on top of it.

I got confused and then I searched on how to upgrade it, finding info here: 
https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Release-Info

So I used the method like this:

```
datalab delete --keep-disk ${VM-Name}
datalab create ${VM-Name}
```

Now I got a new version of the datalab, but my previous code is missing. :( Can anyone help? I think the disk should be kept.. somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

A little confused by the wording of your question: are you saying that the files were missing before you did the upgrade?  If so you should check to make sure you don't have more than one datalab instance running under https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances.

Worst case, if your files were under the $HOME directory (/content in datalab) your notebooks should be in the automatic backup:
https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/working-with-notebooks#cloud_datalab_backup

That said, the disk with your previous files should still be there and should have been used if you used the same VM-Name.  If the new instance has a different name it would not be there.  Check to see if there is an unused disk in https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/disks